# phonegap html5 push notification

Tags: android, ios, html, dreamweaver, phonegap-pushplugin

Hope you can help, I'm trying to implement push notifications with my app, I'm currently building with DreamWeaver/phonegap html5, but the problem I have got, I cannot find a tutorial that will work for both IOS/Android and how can I send notifications from my app to be displayed on the same device?

Thank you